# Can multiple SSL certs be valid?

Tags: ssl, https

We're currently with a webhost that has an SSL cert for us. Unfortuantely (unrelated to our webhost), we are required to move to a new host. While we setup the new host, with new temporary subdomains while we look to move, if we buy a new cert and install it on our new machines, will it "invalidate" the older one (if they cover the same domains)?

ie old webhost has cert for www.oursite.com and oursite.com. New webhost cert will cover new.oursite.com,  oursite.com and www.oursite.com. If there's no DNS change until we're ready to move to the new site, will our old cert be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can multiple SSL certs be valid?

yes

> will our old cert be affected

no

There is no relation between the two certificates. The browser validates the chain from the site's certificate through the CAs until it reaches a trusted (built-in) root CA.

You can either reuse the existing certificate or get a new one, if your new provider enforces it.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple SSL certificates is valid for the same domain. You want to move to new host and your new host provider's giving ssl certificate with host then you should continue with new host provider certificate in place of old one. Don't pay double for ssl certificate.